# Trash can icon animation?

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I'm new here and I just had a question about animating the trash can icon in an iPhone application like in the photo and mail app. I tried using the method [here](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIToolbar) to animate the trash icon in a UINavigationController's toolbar, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Can anyone post a code sample of how to use this method correctly? Thanks

```
-(void)animateToolbarItemIndex:(NSUInteger)index duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration target:(id)target didFinishSelector:(SEL)selector;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no

```
-(void)animateToolbarItemIndex:(NSUInteger)index duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration target:(id)target didFinishSelector:(SEL)selector;
```

method in the official SDK docs. It's likely a private method. Are you working with the official SDK or jailbroken phones?

Comment: Jailbroken phones ;). Also, it is a private method.